# Move your compiled Perl to a new directory

Tags: perl

If I'm compiling and running various versions of Perl, what is the best way to relocate its directory if needed? For example, if I compile Perl 5.22.0 with:

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/perl522
make all
make test
make install
```

But later realize I'd like to move it (and future builds) to a directory called `$HOME/perls/perl522/` -- can it be done merely using a  `mv perl522 ~/perls/` command, or does the `-Dprefix=` command used during the initial `Configure` process intrinsically link that location, thus require a full re-configuration, make, test, etc...?

Is there a best practice / streamlined process for such a circumstance?

Comment: [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/)?

Comment: ideally without perlbrew

Comment: You'll need to fix paths in Config.pm. then check if `@INC` was correctly updated (it's shown by `perl -V`) by comparing the new values with the old ones. If that's correct, you should be ok.

Comment: @ikegami how do you fix the paths in Config.pm?

Comment: Using your favorite text editor

Comment: @ikegami oh, so just edit the Config.pm file? No reconfigure/recompile necessary?

Comment: Well, try it. Config.pm + Config_heavy.pl, actually.

Comment: @ikegami ok will give it a go.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what it is about `perlbrew` that fails your criteria

Comment: Just editing Config.pm will not work. There are paths compiled into the perl binary that are used to, for example, find Config.pm.

Comment: @Borodin I was looking for a native way within Perl to do this, as I don't have the ability to install perlbrew (we only have access to a few CPAN modules at the moment.  But I assume the best way to do such a thing in perlbrew is by using the [sitecustomize.pl](http://perlbrew.pl/Install-a-sitecustomize.pl-file-with-perlbrew.html)

Comment: @CalleDybedahl Based on some testing I've done overnight, it looks like you are correct - there are multiple locations with the `prefix` path compiled in, so modifying `Config.pm` & `Config_heavy.pl` would likely not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `INSTALL` file in the Perl source tree, under the heading "Relocatable @INC". It's possible to do roughly what you want, but it requires compiling perl with a special flag and it has some caveats to it.

Comment: Looks like this is the officially supported Perl way to do it.  Based on the description in the `INSTALL` file in the source, one would need to add the `-Duserelocatableinc` flag at the time `./Configure` is run to enable shifting the forthcoming built Perl to a new location.

Comment: For sure. But the question asked how to move it if you only realized later that you needed to move it.

Comment: Well, as long as you want to move it to a place with a path that's the same length or less than the original path, you could always just edit the hardcoded paths in the perl binary. Emacs hexl-mode works pretty well for that sort of thing.